# Find the class equation for the following groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone please verify these? I'm quite unsure about my answer to the Quaternion Group.

> Find the class equation for the following groups:
>
> (a) The Quaternion group
>
> (b) $D_5$
>
> (c) $D_6$
>
> (d) The Klein four group

(a) $1+1+2+2+2$

(b) $1+2+2+5$

(c) $1+1+3+3+2+2$

(d) $1+1+1+1$

Comment: They are correct. Not sure this is a useful question, though.

Comment: if you mean by the class equation the size of each conjugacy class, yes.   Usually though we put together all of the things in the center,   which means all the ones that are 1 are put together,  so a would be 2+2+2+2,  D would be 4,  and C would 2+3+3+2+2

Comment: Can you show how you got these answers, which are by the way correct?

Answer (score 5):

Class equations:
$|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum[G:c(a)]$, where $a \notin Z(G)$  and $|cl(a)|=[G:c(a)]$

$Q_8=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$

$Z(Q_8)=\{1,-1\}$. $c(i)=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$,$|c(i)|=|c(j)|=|c(k)|=4$. Therefore $|cl(i)|=|cl(j)|=|cl(k)|=2$

$|Q_8|=2+2+2+2$.

$D_5=\{e,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,s,rs,r^2s,r^3s,r^4s\}$, $r^5=s^2=e,rs=sr^4$
. $Z(D_5)=\{e\},cl(r)=\{r,r^4\},cl(r^2)=\{r^3,r^2\},cl(s)=\{rs,r^2s,r^3s,r^4s,s\}$

$|D_5|=1+2+2+5$.

$D_6=\{e,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,r^5,s,rs,r^2s,r^3s,r^4s,r^5s\}$, $r^6=s^2=e,rs=sr^5$

$Z(D_6)=\{e,r^3\},cl(r)=\{r,r^5\},cl(r^2)=\{r^2,r^4\},cl(s)=\{s,r^2s,r^4s\},cl(rs)=\{rs,r^3s,r^5s\}$

$|D_6|=2+2+2+3+3$

$V_4=\{e,a,b,c\},a^2=b^2=c^2=1$ (since $V_4$ is abelian group)

$|V_4|=4(Z(V_4))$